# Jquery selected index problem

Tags: jquery, select

i am trying to make simple show-hide example but i cant select hidden elements with eq() or not().
Basic structure is like this :

```
<ul id="info">
  <li><a href="#">İletişim Adreslerimiz</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Kroki</a></li>
 </ul>
 <ul id="info-ic">
  <li><p>Adres Bilgilerimiz</p></li>
  <li><p>Kroki Bilgisi</p></li>
 </ul>
```

and jquery code :

```
$('#info > li').click(function(){
 $('#info-ic').find('li:eq('+$(this).index()+')').show();
 $('#info-ic').find('li:not('+$(this).index()+')').hide();
});
```

Comment: in the second line, you're looking for 'li:not(...' inside another li, that won't work. :]

Comment: yes thank you i notice after i add question.

Answer (score 2):

`find()` searches the *descendants* of the selected elements, not the elements themselves. Use:

```
$('#info-ic > li:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')')
$('#info > li:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')')
```

Or:

```
$('#info-ic').children('li:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')')
$('#info').children('li:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')')
```